# Mysql connection timeout in doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have developed a application which send large number of emails to different users in batches. The most common problem I faced in this application is the problem of mysql connection timeout. In between the batches when there is no queries executed in the previously opened connection and connection remained idle for long time, mysql itself close the connection. After sending the current batch when I again try to execute any sql query it gives me mysql connection error.

Right now I am using mysql_ping($conn) function to check whether the connection id timedout or not. If the connect is timed out I connect again with mysql_connect() function. Now I am moving to doctrine rather than native PHP function. Is there a recconnect() function in Doctorine as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Never faced this problem with my batch actions but I think you could probably do something like this in those places in your code where you think there's a risk the connection will time out:

```
// Fetch current connection
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
if(!$conn) {
   // Open a new connection
   $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://username:password@localhost/whatever', 'connection 1');
}
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/connections.html

Comment: Hi Tom, I am afraid your solution is not going to work because there is no way in doctrine to make the value of connections null when the connection get timedout.

Comment: @Tejaswi... I see. In this case, I'm not experienced enough to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There's a custom bundle that allow connection to reopen:
https://github.com/facile-it/doctrine-mysql-come-back

You can set a maximum amount of retry, or you can manually call method retry on Connection!